# CTRL, ALT, SHIFT or right-click kills some windows

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, crash, segmentation-fault

For the last few days, certain desktop applications have started dying whenever the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are pressed, or the GUI is right-clicked. This happens on keydown/mousedown.

For example, it happens in:

- Nautilus
- Update Manager
- Rhythmbox Music Player
- Gnome Screenshot
- Gedit (only seems to crash on right-click and some keystrokes such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

It does not happen in all applications. For example, Chrome, Clion (IDE), Skype, gitk are unaffected.

If I launch `nautilus` from the command line, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
$ nautilus
Segmentation fault
```

Running it with `gdb` shows the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff474a1c8 in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff475abe7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff4763098 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff4763352 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff6ea616b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff6f1b095 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff6ea61d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff6dbc027 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff6ea61d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff6ee20a1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff6ea61d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff6e68fd0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff6ea61d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff6fe2d49 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff6ea61d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff6ea62ab in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff6fe9233 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff474a1c8 in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff475abe7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff4763098 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff4763352 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff6fd895c in gtk_widget_show () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#23 0x000000000047563c in ?? ()
#24 0x0000000000479871 in ?? ()
#25 0x00007ffff6ea818e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#26 0x00007ffff474a3f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff4762708 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff4763352 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff6fcee5c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff6ea5cf8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#31 0x00007ffff6ea76f7 in gtk_main_do_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#32 0x00007ffff6a5bc22 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#33 0x00007ffff4476bd4 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#34 0x00007ffff4476e18 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#35 0x00007ffff4476ebc in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#36 0x00007ffff4a2e0bc in g_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#37 0x000000000042b561 in ?? ()
#38 0x00007ffff394aec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x42b4a0, argc=0x1, argv=0x7fffffffdf98, init=<optimised out>, fini=<optimised out>, rtld_fini=<optimised out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdf88) at libc-start.c:287
#39 0x000000000042b5c3 in ?? ()
```

I've noticed that nautilus looks different since this started happening:

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
$ uname -a
Linux bert 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

---

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` are:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
# deb http://ppa.launchpad/gnurubuntu/rubuntu/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad/gnurubuntu/rubuntu/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ raring universe
```

Comment: Have you installed one of the elementary-os/daily or gnome3-team/gnome3 PPAs?

Comment: @PabloZubieta, yes, at some point I did try an elementary app (the music player, whose name I have forgotten). Great thinking -- I'll take a look.

Comment: `gdb` backtrace for `gedit` is [here](http://pastebin.com/SXFPm2H6). It's very similar to the one listed above.

Comment: It seems that the updates come from a ricotz PPA (ppa:ricotz/testing). You should make sure it is activated to ppa-purge it. You may also want to look if you have the gnome3-team/gnome3 and gnome3-team/gnome3-staging PPA's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have installed a PPA (probably the elementary-os/daily or the ricotz/testing) that installed a library (or libraries) of GNOME that is (are) incompatible with your system.

You should purge the PPA that installed the newer version of the library (libraries).

If you do not have installed `ppa-purge`, run

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Once installed remove the PPA with

```
sudo ppa-purge [ppa:ppa_team/ppa_name]
```

Comment: You're right. I have _http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu trusty_ in my PPA list. Running `sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/stable` seems to have reverted `gir1.2-wnck-3.0/trusty libwnck-3-0:amd64/trusty libwnck-3-common/trusty`. I'll reboot and see how it went.

Comment: After rebooting, nautilus still looks different and crashes as described beforehand. Can you think of anything else I should try?

Comment: I would also try with `ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily`.

Additionally, If you had a PPA (that may have installed a new version of libgir and/or libgtk) at the moment of the upgrade, and then deactivated you need to enable it again and ppa-purge it.

Comment: Thanks. The `daily` variant was never added, so the command failed. I can't think what other PPAs might have been added in the past. Is there a way to reinstall a specific version of these two libraries?

Comment: What are the outputs of `dpkg -s gir1.2-gtk-3.0`, `dpkg -s libgtk-3-0` and `dpkg -s libgtk-3-common`?

Comment: Thanks for following up. The output of those commands is [available here](http://pastebin.com/u2faKSX2).

Comment: It seems that the updates come from a ricotz PPA (ppa:ricotz/testing). You should make sure it is activated to ppa-purge it. You may also want to look if you have the gnome3-team/gnome3 and gnome3-team/gnome3-staging PPA's.

Comment: Fantastic! Adding that PPA then purging it has my machine back in a working state. Thank you SO much. I would upvote you 100 times :) In case it helps anyone else, here is a [log](http://pastebin.com/kUEQq1Q1) showing the fix. I still have no idea how that PPA was added in the first place.